# How to read a jira attachement content without downloading it in python?

Tags: python, jira, filereader, python-jira

I am working with python-jira, I want to get the attachments(only excel or csv) data from an issue into a readable format(say pandas df for example) without downloading the files.

Is there any ways to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to just download it. Otherwise you have to access the Jira file system (on-prem Jira only), work out where the file is in the file system, and download it.